# How to solve Laravel "Payload is invalid"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a big problem with my laravel application on production mode only...

I don't know when it's firing, but this website is around 10k visitors/day and my laravel log file is so big now..

Here you can find the log :

```
The payload is invalid. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Encryption\\DecryptException(code: 0): The payload is invalid. at /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:195)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php(136): Illuminate\\Encryption\\Encrypter->getJsonPayload(NULL)
#1 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(154): Illuminate\\Encryption\\Encrypter->decrypt('eyJpdiI6Ik1wN0p...', false)
#2 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(136): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->getTokenFromRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#3 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(74): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->tokensMatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#5 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#6 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 /home/web/abuk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
```

I really don't know from where it comes..

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652194/laravel-decryptexception-the-payload-is-invalid

Comment: Are you encrypting data somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the cache with the following command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Dont forget to include the csrf in your forms
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf

Comment: I think that it solved the problem using php artisan cache:clear ...
Why?

Comment: I'm not sure, laravel caches some configurations on your local environment and when we move our applications to the production those configurations still there so it is important to clear the cache. (just my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: 
1- php artisan clear; or 
2- make sure you application generated APP_KEY, if not do php artisan key: generate
3- if you are using Jwt make sure JWT_SECRET was generated, if not do php artisan jwt:secret

Answer (score 0):

May be you frogot _token in the form
@csrf