# Laravel Sanctum CSRF returns 419 for unprotected routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I have a SPA app where I try to implement Sanctum's CSRF protection.

From docs:

> To authenticate your SPA, your SPA's "login" page should first make a request to the /sanctum/csrf-cookie endpoint to initialize CSRF protection for the application

Right now I request CSRF token before I login

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
   // Login...
});
```

Should I request CSRF token before doing ANY post request in my application?
If yes, I basically need to request a CSRF token before routes like `POST api/password_reset`, `POST api/tracking`, `POST api/register` etc.

Or is there any way to tell Laravel Sanctum to only return `419` `CSRF token mismatch` errors for protected routes, ie. routes with `auth:sanctum` middleware?

**EDIT**:

Just wanted to make it clear that I don't have an issue with CSRF implementation in general. It works great after I have requested the CSRF token. Axios will add the token in all subsequent requests. My question is really about when to do the first request to CSRF token.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 7 Vue 2 Sanctum Login Error 419; CSRF Token Mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527334/laravel-7-vue-2-sanctum-login-error-419-csrf-token-mismatch)

Comment: @BhavinSolanki No that doesn't help unfortunately. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for something similar and I stumbled upon this; [Laravel: How to Avoid TokenMismatchException CSRF Token on certain routes using a method](https://tutsforweb.com/how-to-avoid-tokenmismatchexception-csrf-token-on-certain-routes-in-laravel-using-a-method/)

You can therefore kindly exclude the routes from being checked for CSRF token by adding the route path in `$except` array in `VerifyCsrfToken` class inside the `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` like shown below;

```
protected $except = [
    '/api/password_reset',
    '/api/tracking',
    '/api/register',
];
```

This can be seen also in Laravel Official Documentation [Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)